# Fixing Firefox File Selection Window From Opening Behind All Other Windows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using vBulletin and currently when someone using FireFox clicks on "Select Files" to upload attachments, the file window prompt is opening up behind all other windows on their computer.

This is the code I found which I believe relates to the function calling the window to open:

```
<div id="asset_addfiles">
        <div id="selectall2"<vb:if condition="!$attachcount"> class="hidden"</vb:if>><label for="selectallbox2">{vb:rawphrase select_all} <input type="checkbox" id="selectallbox2" name="selectall2" value="1" tabindex="1" /></label></div>
        {vb:rawphrase selected_attachments} 
        <button type="button" id="insert_inline" class="button" title="{vb:rawphrase insert_attachments_in_window}">{vb:rawphrase insert_inline_x, 0}</button>      
        <button type="button" id="insert_attachment" class="button">{vb:rawphrase done}</button>
    </div>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        var assetobj = new vB_Asset("assetobj", "asset_category_tree", "{vb:raw posthash}", "{vb:raw poststarttime}", "{vb:raw contenttypeid}", "{vb:raw bbuserinfo.userid}", {vb:raw auth_type}, {vb:raw asset_enable}, "{vb:raw insertinline}");
        <vb:if condition="$show['updateparent']">
            if (typeof window.opener != 'undefined' && typeof window.opener.vB_Attachments != 'undefined')
            {
                window.opener.vB_Attachments.reset();
                {vb:raw new_attachlist_js}
            }
        </vb:if>

    //-->
    </script>
    <!-- This element is cloned via javascript since IE doesn't like one to alter file input -->
    <form action="">
    <input id="uploadinput" type="file" class="bginput uploadinput" name="attachment[]" size="30" style="display:none" tabindex="1" />
    </form>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: is there a popup window from where the file chooser appears? seems too much code is shown, <input type=file> is all that's needed, and it should appear up-front when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID or a CSS class to the form and give it a z-index in css.

```
<form id="uploadinputform" action="">
```

and the css would be:

```
#uploadinputform { z-index: 9; }
```

Or do an inline style hack like so:

```
<form style="z-index: 9;" action="">
```